# remove thousand dots in a column in a table in a mysql joomla database

Tags: mysql, joomla

Joomla, mysql database. laqdf_base  Table qdf_joomleague_person: in knvbnr field you can see numbers in different formats  22.333.333 and 12345678.

What exactly (for a very fresh newbie) do I have to do, within PhpMyAdmin to update the table so all numbers in knvbnr shows numbers in 12345678 format (no "." in them)
I cant post images cause I dont have 10 points yet! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL's `replace()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function. Example:

```
update qdf_joomleague_person set knvbnr = replace(knvbnr, '.', '');
```